# can't find gazebo /world dir

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**hello everyone , i follow the tutorial below , but when i type "$  env | grep GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH " ,there are nothing happen . i can't see anything in my terminate.**

World files are found within the /worlds directory of your Gazebo resource path. The location of this path depends on how you installed Gazebo and the type of system your are on. To find the location of your Gazebo resources, use the following command:

env | grep GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH

An typical path might be something like /usr/local/share/gazebo-1.9. Add /worlds to the end of the path and you should have the directory containing the world files Gazebo uses, including the mud.world file.

**if anyone know why , help me please~**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200356/can%27t-find-gazebo-/world-dir/) by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2015-01-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like a `Gazebo` specific question, which should better be asked on [its designated forum](http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0